# LDAP Berkeley DB

Tags: ldap, openldap, berkeleydb

I'm trying to configure slapd on my machine and I keep getting this error. I can recover at times using db7.7_recover but not always. I see this problem if the slapd deamon is killed for any reason.

Isn't a DB supposed to be able to take care of these failures? Is there a patch I can apply to BDB for this?

```
root@anurag-desktop:/etc/ldap# slapd -d 256 -f /etc/ldap/slapd.sssc.conf &
[1] 4820
root@anurag-desktop:/etc/ldap# @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.21 (Dec 19 2011 15:40:04) $
    buildd@allspice:/build/buildd/openldap-2.4.21/debian/build/servers/slapd
/etc/ldap/slapd.sssc.conf: line 22: rootdn is always granted unlimited privileges.
/etc/ldap/slapd.sssc.conf: line 26: rootdn is always granted unlimited privileges.
bdb_db_open: database "dc=sssc,dc=org": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
bdb(dc=sssc,dc=org): /usr/local/var/slapd-logs: Permission denied
bdb(dc=sssc,dc=org): PANIC: Permission denied
bdb(dc=sssc,dc=org): unable to join the environment
bdb_db_open: database "dc=sssc,dc=org" cannot be recovered, err -30974. Restore from backup!
bdb(dc=sssc,dc=org): txn_checkpoint interface requires an environment configured for the transaction subsystem
bdb_db_close: database "dc=sssc,dc=org": txn_checkpoint failed: Invalid argument (22).
backend_startup_one (type=bdb, suffix="dc=sssc,dc=org"): bi_db_open failed! (-30974)
bdb_db_close: database "dc=sssc,dc=org": alock_close failed
slapd stopped.
```

I dumped the logfile using db4.7_logfile and I can't figure out what call fails the permissions.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you see this answer? http://serverfault.com/questions/313411/ldap-dying-for-unknown-reasons

Comment: Actually I did do a chown -R openldap:openldap /var/lib/ldap still the  kernel "open" call fails. I dont have the logs to post (sorry). Maybe an apparmor thing.